# How do I skip PropType validation of a React component prop?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I'm trying to use a 3rd party React component with an incorrect PropType definition. Passing the problematic value to the component as a prop works just fine but is not accepted by the validator. How do I tell the validator to skip validation of the prop with the incorrect validation rule?